# Update of Text Field In SharePoint List Using Rest Returns An Error Code of 400

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list called "Search Results"
There is a field in the list called "Users" which I am trying to set to the value "Test" for a specific record ID.

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
                try{

                                var item = {
                                                "__metadata": { "type":  "SP.Data.SearchResultsListItem" },
                                                "Users":  "Test"
                                };

                                $.ajax({
                                                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Search Results')/items(174)",
                                                type: "POST",
                                                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                                                headers: {
                                                                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                                                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                                                                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                                                                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                                                },
                                                success: function (data) {
                                                                alert('Field was updated!');
                                                                
                                                },
                                                error: function(jqXHR, exception)  {
                                                                alert(jqXHR.status);
                                                }
                                });
                }
                catch(err){
                      alert(err);
                }

});
```

I get error code of 400 returned.

In the Chrome console, I get a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" message and then a link.

When I click on the link, I can see the record in SharePoint on my screen. I can see my "Users" field.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how to proceed with troubleshooting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is space in List Name "Search Results", then the type shoule like this:

```
  var item = {
                "__metadata": { "type":  "SP.Data.Search_x0020_ResultsListItem" },
                "Users":  "Test"
              };
```

Comment: Thank you, Jerry_MSFT!!

Answer (score 0):

First try to run that URL in browser and check its returning results or not. Then go for the rest.

www.WebsiteURL.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Search Results')/items(174)

If its returning results find the metadate value from that and verify your metadata value as well..